# grouping IN statement sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

lets say I have a table called table1 and it's corresponding columns are col1, col2, col3 and col4 for example.

what will be the equivalent thing of doing:

```
-- note that the following query will not work
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE col1, col2 IN (SELECT col1, col2 
                        FROM table1 
                       WHERE col3 < 4)
```

Do I have to merge col1 and col2 in my database to make this work? If I merge col1 and col2 into col1_2 then I will be able to make the above query work by writing:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE col1_2 IN (SELECT col1_2 
                    FROM table1 
                   WHERE col3 < 4)
```

The IN clause works fine when using one column. it will be nice if I could use it with several columns without having to modify the database.

Comment: Maybe it's late, but isn't that the same as `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col3 < col4`?

Comment: No, its not quite the same.  Imagine the simple case of two rows, with identical col1,col2 values, but row1 has col3 < col4 and row2 has col3 > col4.  In the desired case, both rows would be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * from table1 t1, table1 t2
where t1.col1=t2.col1 and t1.COl2=t2.Col2 and t1.col3<4
```

try this one

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent of what you showed  is:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 tb1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM table1 tb2
    WHERE 
        tb1.col1 = tb2.col1 and 
        tb1.col2 = tb2.col2 and
        tb2.col3 < 4
)
```

However, this query does not make much sense as it is equivalent of

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 tb1
WHERE tb2.col3 < 4
```

I just assume that the example you show is not well thought out.