# grouping IN statement sql part 2( negating it)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I will like to do the opposite of [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352448/grouping-in-statement-sql).  In other words how could I do something like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE col1, col2 NOT IN (SELECT col1, col2 
                            FROM table1
                           WHERE col3 < 4)
```

Note the `NOT` clause.

EDIT

I am editing the question to explain what I am trying to do.

so I have the following table:
[image]

note that every time I scan a directory I enter the files that where found in this table (table1). By looking at the table we know that the first time I scan the directory there where files A and B. The second time we scan the directory we can say that files A and B where still there with an additional file C. we also know that on the second scan file A was modified because it has a different dateModified. I am interested in the last scan. From looking at it I know that we still have files A, B, and C with the addition of file X and modification of file B. That's why I wanted to build the query

```
select * from table1 
WHERE FileID, DateModified NOT IN 
(SELECT Path, DateModified From table1 WHERE DateInserted<4)
```

hoping to get files X and B because those are the files that are not in all records with DateInserted<4 . Sorry for not explaining my self clearly.

Comment: Are you just trying to make some points on the questions?

Comment: I understand the functionality (two columns) to be called "tuples"

Comment: and if you guys try to use the solutions found in this solution I will not get files X and B. Sorry for not explaining my self correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't like my answer there, I will post it here and will add `NOT` :).

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 tb1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM table1 tb2
    WHERE 
        tb1.col1 = tb2.col1 and 
        tb1.col2 = tb2.col2 and
        tb2.col3 < 4
)
```

And like I said there, the query as is does not make sense as it is equivalent of

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 tb1
WHERE tb2.col3 >= 4
```

**[EDIT]** Update is based on the comment:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableSource tb1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM tableDestination tb2
    WHERE 
        tb1.col1 = tb2.col1 and 
        tb1.col2 = tb2.col2 and
        tb2.col3 < 4
)
```

Comment: I don't know why I cannot make your query work :( . I am basically inserting new records in a table and I am trying to see if a combination of col1 and col2 already exist in that table. I actually want to get the ones that do not exist.

Comment: @Tono Nam - so you have two tables? One is the source and another is a destination and you are inserting from source to destination and you need to check if the destination already has the row?

Comment: maybe I explained my self incorrectly thanks for the help :) . I don't know why it does not work. I will still try to play around with it

Comment: @Tono Nam - you can try to elaborate your question. Add examples. What are the tables, what is the input. What is the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from table1 t1, table1 t2
where t1.col3=t2.col3 and t1.COl4=t2.Col4 AND 
t1.col1!=t2.col1 and t1.COl2!=t2.Col2 and t1.col3<4
```

Try the above Query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2 AND t2.col3 < 4
WHERE t2.col1 IS NULL  /* col2 or col3 would do as well,
                          just like any non-nullable column would */
```